# How to use Intel fortran compiler with MKL on command line

Tags: xcode, command-line, fortran, intel-fortran, intel-mkl

I've freshly installed the Intel® Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for Fortran OS X* (student version). It comes with the Math Kernel Library, which is why I bought it. I'm having a hard time getting started with MKL. Here's what I've done step-by-step.

1) Installed Intel® Parallel Studio XE Composer Edition for Fortran OS X* (no problem). I can run a 'hello world' script using `ifort` and throw the `-mkl` link command on at the end with no problem (not calling any mkl commands just yet).

2) Following [these instructions](https://plafrim.bordeaux.inria.fr/lib/exe/fetch.php?media=utilisation:outils_intel:mkl-10.2.7.041-userguide.pdf) I  set my environment variables using a script provided by intel (located in opt/intel/bin to be precise). I have the intel 64-bit architecture (according to `ifort -V`) so I use `bash mklvars.sh intel64 mod ilp64`. It runs without error (or any output).

3) I write the following code to use MKL's [gemm](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/468480) command for fortran95. Just multiplying 2 matrices.

```
program test

implicit none
real, dimension(2,2) :: testA, testB, testC

testA = 1
testB = 1
testC = 0  ! I don't think I need this line, but it shouldn't matter

call gemm(testA, testB, testC)

write(*,*) testC

end program test
```

4) I compile with `ifort test_mkl.f90 -o test -mkl`. I get the following error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_gemm_", referenced from:
      _MAIN__ in ifortSTVOrB.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

5) I try `ifort test_mkl.f90 -o test  -L/opt/intel/mkl/lib -mkl` and get the same result.

I notice a lot of people using MKL begin their code with `USE mkl95_blas, ONLY: gemm`, so I put that in above `implicit none` in both of the above examples and get:

```
    test_mkl.f90(4): error #7002: Error in opening the compiled module file.  Check INCLUDE paths.   [MKL95_BLAS]
    USE mkl95_blas, ONLY: gemm
--------^
test_mkl.f90(12): error #6406: Conflicting attributes or multiple declaration of name.   [GEMM]
    call gemm(testA, testB, testC )
---------^
test_mkl.f90(4): error #6580: Name in only-list does not exist.   [GEMM]
    USE mkl95_blas, ONLY: gemm
--------------------------^
compilation aborted for test_mkl.f90 (code 1)
```

Any ideas as to what the problem is or how to fix this? I have successfully [run a simple script in XCODE](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/quick-link-intel-mkl-in-xcode-ide-a-fortran-sample) using MKL, so it's definitely something I'm doing and not my installation.

Comment: See if you can find the path of that module...

Comment: You must set up your environment for the rigjt include paths. This is a typical question you should ask at the Intel Support forums, you pay for your support.

Comment: Thanks Vladimir, I tried the Intel Support forum for MKL after seeing your comment and found some help there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation tells you to use the "source" command on the provided compilervars.sh script to make all the resources available. For example:

source  //bin/compilervars.sh

This will add MKL to the include and library paths so that the compiler and linker can find them. If you need more help, please ask in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-fortran-compiler-for-linux-and-mac-os-x  You can get MKL-specific help in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-math-kernel-library

Comment: Also, apparently the .mod files in OS X are named differently than elsewhere. I changed my 'use' statement to: USE blas95, which reflects the name of my .mod file. That change + your suggestion on the source command did the trick. (Specifically, I looked at [this link](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/281190) ).

Comment: No, what happened is that MKL changed the names of the modules in a newer MKL version. See the MKL release notes for details.

Comment: This does not seem to work under windows : after running compilervas.bat inside a cmd windows and compiling the canonical test_dgemm.f90 yields to a "error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol DGEMM referenced in function MAIN__" error.

Comment: You need to name the MKL library or libraries you want to use - it is not done automatically. If you add the `-mkl` option, the ifort driver will add some common MKL libraries, so you can try that. Otherwise, use the MKL Link Line Advisor (https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/onemkl/link-line-advisor.html) to select the set to use.

Answer (score 0):

I think your program has some bugs, first, you have to include blas95 at the beginning of your code, then, you can't use `gemm`, you have to choose the specific version of `gemm`. For example, to do real number matrix multiplication, you have to use `dgemm`, here is my code(Which I called `test.f90`), which compiles successfully using `ifort -mkl test.f90 -o test.exe`

```
program test
    use blas95
    implicit none
    real*8,dimension(2,2)::testA,testB,testC
    integer::i,j
    testA=1d0
    testB=1d0
    testC=1d0
    call dgemm("N", "N", 2, 2, 2, 1d0, A, 2, B, 2, 0, C, 2)
    print *, testC
end program test
```

Comment: I do agree that the code in the question is incorrect. But one should only do one of those options. Either use the old interface and select sgemm or dgemm or or use the blas95 module and then one can use the gemm generic (with a much simpler interface). Of course a programs doing both is not incorrect, but then the module is used for no useful purpose.